# Regarding Drupal 7 configuring with apache Solr and apache Nutch

Tags: apache, drupal, solr, drupal-7, nutch

I have installed drupal 7 and the apache solr search module and configured with Apache Solr(solr version:4.10.4). The content has been indexed from the drupal to the apache solr and searching also works fine.I need to configure Nutch(Apache Nutch Version:1.12) web crawler to the apache solr and drupal 7 and to fetch the details from the specific URL (for eg: http://www.w3schools.com) and need to search in the drupal for the contents. My problem is how to configure all three solr nutch and drupal 7.Can any one suggest the solution for this?

Comment: Hi @Ramesh! I don't think you need to integrate Nutch because it's a crawler, it does not need to receive info from inside your Drupal 7, like Apache Solr. The only things that need Nutch is to be able to crawl your site, so it needs access and possibly a sitemap but not an integration. Right?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. As you said is correct i have configured the Drupal and apache solr by copying the schema.xml,solrconfig.xml and protwords.txt files from apache solr search module it works fine with indexing and searching. The contents are indexed to the core. Now the apache nutch has the crawled data. This to be moved to apache solr core. For that we need to change the apache solr schema.xml file as it as in the nutch. If i move this nutch and apache solr works fine with indexing the contents to the solr Core.

Comment: What i need is the crawled content (nutch content) also to be indexed and contents(drupal 7) from the site also to be indexed in the same core in apache solr. For this what are the steps to be follow can you assist me in this?

Comment: Oooook... Let me see if I understand... Do you want to index in Solr the full pages of your site crawled with Nutch?

Comment: I'm thinking a very "ugly" solution without Nutch... Is Nutch a requirement? Could Solr index your nodes for specific displays? Are you somehow experienced with Drupal?

Comment: I have an external resource in my site that has been built up in html having some pdf files that to be indexed and need to search in drupal 7 for that i used nutch as a web crawler to index the hyperlinks and contents.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... here's my ugly solution that maybe fits in what you are doing.

You can use a php field (a custom field with Display Suite) in your node (or page) which basically reads your full page with CURL and then print the contents right there. This field should be only in a display of your node that will see nobody (except Apache Solr).

Finally in Solr config (which honestly I don't remember well how it worked) you could choose which display of the page to be indexed, or the field to be indexed, which will be your full page.

If all these works, you don't need to integrate Nutch with Solr and Drupal.

Good luck :)

PD: If you have a doubt just ask.

Comment: Sorry beto you have understand wrongly. In my site i have link (forms) which directs to the html page.The html page has some files with the hyperlinks. i need those file details like hyperlinks and etc... for that i can use only nutch to crawl the data and can integrate with solr. my problem is i need to index the data that i have crawled form the nutch and i need to index the contents that are available in drupal to apache solr.

Comment: for that we need to merge the schema.xml file from the apache nutch and the module (apache solr search) in drupal7. can you assist me on this

Comment: Hi @Ramesh I'm not too familiar with the Drupal schema but you could just diff the different `schema.xml` and manually inspect whats happening. Basically the `fieldTypes` although could have different names in both files, will map with the same class, so you basically just have to pick which one you want, copy the fields from the other schema and seeing what is required and what is not required, the idea is to make the schema as flexible as possible so only keep the `required` attribute on the minimum amount of fields as possible.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents on this: looks like you want to aggregate content from your Drupal site (your nodes) and from an external content hosted on your site but not as a Drupal content right? If this is the case then you don't need to any integration between Nutch and Drupal, just to index everything in the same Solr core/collection. Of course you'll need to make sure that the Solr schema is compatible (Nutch has it's own metadata different from the Drupal nodes). Also if you index in separated cores/collections you could use the `shards` parameter to span you query to several cores and still get only one result set, but with this approach you'll need to keep and eye on the relevance of your results (the order of the documents) and also keep and eye on what fields the Drupal Solr module uses to show the result, so in the end you'll still need to make the schema of both cores compatible at some degree.

Comment: Thanks Jorge for your valuable answer. i need to index both the drupal content and nutch crawled content to the same core in solr. can you give some ideas to integrate schema.xml form drupal module and nutch in solr schema.xml